# Change opacity and scale properties of the footer according to the scroll position from Bottom (example inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the website I'm working on, my fixed footer is:  footer id="footer"

I want to change its css property according to its position from the bottom of the page:

from

```
opacity: 0;transform: scale(0.98);
```

to

```
opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);
```

when the footer comes inside the viewport (opacity 0, scale(0.98), the footer opacity and scale must change accordingly related to the bottom position.

When the scroller position reach the bottom the opacity is set to 1 and scale(1);

this is what happens exactly to the footer of this website: http://www.spon.com/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use what are called events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

You should watch the "scroll" event.

Example:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  // Here you want to determine your conditions
  // (how close to the bottom, if the footer is in view etc)
  // and make any changes you want to happen

});
```

Comment: Yes I know what you mean but it's easy to count pixel from the top with scrollTop but I don't know the maths to detemine the pixel value from the bottom since there's no scrollBottom in jQuery.

Comment: If you are using jQuery an easy way to check visibility is     $('#footer:visible').length

Comment: I'll finally use skrollr.